Problem using Link component when incrementally migrating from page to app router with dynamic roting
I'm attempting to move a large next.js app from the page router to app router and running into an issue where the <Link/> component isn't handling the routing well.
An example of the files that are getting tripped up:
├── app
│   └── [locale]
│       └── dynamic
│           └── page.tsx
└── pages
    ├── [locale]
    │   └── [static]
    │       └── index.tsx
    └── index.tsx


When the index page tries to link to the dynamic page with /en-US/dynamic the [static] page is loaded instead of the dynamic page. This only happens when using the <Link/> component. The data requested from the server comes from the dynamic page, but the component attempts to be displayed on the client side is the [static].
When the page is reloaded or directly accessed, the correct data and components are loaded for the page.
The [static] page is a dynamic catch-all page that is used to serve content that is created from headless cms, so trying not to move away from it having dynamic routing.
Is there an easy workaround for this to ease the migration to the app router?
